# Auto update the height of a div when contents change (validation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

It's a bit hard to explain, but if you go here: http://ewsprojects.com/~lyons, click on Login | Register, clear the registration form, and try to submit, you'll get a validation error (Field required)

You'll see that the form does not update the height to compensate for the increase. I've tried everything, padding, margin, different height values, etc.

I know this question lacks a lot of info, but I'm not sure what else I can put. If you need anything to help you answer, let me know and I'll get right on it.

Comment: simply add a `<br>` http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/1489/58195909.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the height from the style of the div with id 'osx-container' and it would automatically take the height of the content.

**Update**:
adding `$('#osx-container').css({'height':'auto'});` in the Open function in the osx.js file solved the problem. Added it there as the height was calculated every time the dialog box was opened and hence had to be reset to auto every time.

Comment: I tried this earlier using `<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#osx-container").css("height", "");
 </script>`, but it didn't quite work. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: You don't remove it using JavaScript, just don't have it in the code at all. The style attribute of the 'osx-container' should have just these values `style="z-index: 1002; width: 600px; position: absolute; left: 375px; top: 0px; "` without height.

Comment: Also, add a break `<br />` before the error message label to display it in next line as that would look much better that what is looks now.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the height value as it's a modal dialog thing. Looking though.

Comment: I think its buried deep into this plugin code. Is there anything like the code I tried above that would just get rid of the height?

Comment: try removing the `{height: h},` from **d.container.animate** in open function in the **osx.js** file.

Comment: Well, that definitely did something if you look now. Height barely moves past the yellow paragraph part.

Comment: also try removing the `minHeight: 80,` in _$("#osx-modal-content").modal_

Comment: I just tried that right before you commented. Reduces height to 40px

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6120/discussion-between-mark-lyons-and-virendra)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've already accepted an answer, this is much less complicated and would probably be helpful:

The problem is, `<label>` is an inline element and therefore it would just display right next to your `<input>`s. By adding `display:block` you would make the label display as a block element and take an entire new line. However, it would occupy the entire line and probably wouldn't look like the way you wished. At that point, you may either leave it is block and specify the width, or you can use the new CSS3 `inline-block` which will display it like a block but rather than taking up the whole line, it will wrap around its child elements.
If you're concerned about non-CSS3 browsers (however since you're using the HTML5 "placeholder" attribute, I doubt you are) the simplest and easiest way out, would probably be adding the `<br>`... otherwise I recommend `display:inline-block;`